Is there a performance difference between refactoring components into functions inside the component body vs splitting it into different components?
Say I have a component with a long return statement.
const LongReturnComponent = () => {
  //lots of state
  return (
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  )
}

Then I refactor it, for readability purposes into smaller functions inside that component's body
const RefactoredComponent = () => {
   //lots of state
   const function1 = () => {
     .
     .
   }
   const function2 = () => {
     .
     .
   }
   return (
   <>
     {function1()}
     {function2()}
     .
     .
   </>
   )
}

Would there be a performance gain if I extracted function1 and function2 into separate React components, or rather, is that the standard practice? Does React differentiate between components written inside a component's body vs a separate component? My intuition says yes but is it a significant improvement?
What's holding me back from doing this is that I'd have to pass around 20 state variables down to the child components, and also type annotate the props so it gets messy real quick

well basically big components with lots of state is antipattern because if one state is changing the whole component will be rerendering which is slow

@VladVladov so what's the right thing to do if I need that big state across all the child components? load it into a store?

depends on your implementation - maybe use state manager or react context. There is a good video from Jack Herrington called "Are Your React Components Too BIG?"


Would there be a performance gain if I extracted function1 and function2 into separate React components

It has the potential to gain performance, but it won't be automatic. By splitting it up into separate components you may be able to skip rendering some components that have not changed.
For example, you could wrap one of the child components in React.memo. That way even if the parent needs to rerender the child might be able to skip rendering, thus improving performance.
Or if your current combined component is accessing some value from context, and you can make it so only a child component needs that value, then the parent might be able to skip rendering when that value changes.

or rather, is that the standard practice?

Splitting up a component is a common thing to do, but the decision of when to do that depends on the details of your implementation. Sometimes you can get performance improvements as i mentioned, other times you can't, since everything will have to render anyway.
Even if no performance can be gained, you should consider splitting components up to make the code easier to understand. Having separate components makes clear boundaries between what code is related to what and can help with mental chunking.

Does React differentiate between components written inside a component's body vs a separate component?

One thing i want to distinguish: It is very important to not define components inside the body of another component. Your current example doesn't do that; it's making functions, but it never uses those functions as though it is a component.
In other words, the following works even if it's unusual:
const RefactoredComponent = () => {
   const function1 = () => {
     .
     .
   }
   return (
   <>
     {function1()}

But this would be a problem:
const RefactoredComponent = () => {
   const Function1 = () => {
     .
     .
   }

   return (
   <>
     <Function1/>

If you do the latter, then react must unmount/remount Function1 on every render. This has a small performance hit but more importantly it will reset focus and states on every render. You must move the components outside instead.
const Function1 = () => {
  .
  .
}

const RefactoredComponent = () => {
  return (
  <>
    <Function1/>

